# How to run a correlation analysis for numeric columns in R?

Tags: r, subset, correlation

I need to run a correlation analysis on a data frame where some columns are not numeric. I'd like to remove the non-numeric columns from the analysis, if possible without doing it manually.
I've tried this but it's not retrieving any results:

```
library(ISLR)
library(corrplot)
head(Carseats)
X<-cor(Carseats[apply(Carseats, function(x) !is.factor(x))])
corrplot(X)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

I've seen some code using is.numeric, but the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty close:

```
myColumns <- sapply(Carseats, function(x) !is.factor(x))
X<-cor(Carseats[, myColumns])
```

Comment: It worked. I was using "apply", which coerces all columns of a dataframe to the least common supertype, that's not the case of "sapply"

Comment: Sure thing @Lucas Massuh. If this did what asked, you could accept it as the answer.